# Log when cronjobs has started

Tags: cron

I have a file which contains a bunch of cron jobs:

```
30 * * * * someexec somefile
30 1 * * * someexec somefile
30 5 * * * someexec somefile
```

I'd like for when these cron jobs have been activated that something in the fashion of "Cron job someexec somfile has started" to the log file `/var/log/cronjobs.log` for example.

I do not want to log what these cron jobs echo when they do run as I have already fixed that. I only want to log that the jobs are active.

Comment: Side note: If you are running the same command, you can use commas in the time fields to list multiple entries

Comment: `/var/log/syslog` should have log messages when cron jobs are run.

Comment: @Barmar Ahh good to know!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have more than one command in a cron job so something like

```
30 * * * * echo "somexec somefile has started >>/var/log/cronjobs.log"; someexec somefile
```

should do the trick.

You may though want to prefix your message with something so that you know when it happened

```
30 * * * * echo "`date` somexec somefile has started >>/var/log/cronjobs.log"; someexec somefile
```